# Forcing app to show Alerts instead of banners

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, alarm

In iOS5, the default setting for an app notification is **Banners**. Is there a way to force it to force it to be an **Alert/Prompt** within the app or settings. For my app, alert-prompts are more ideal. I'm trying to avoid having the user change it to alerts on their side, and take care of it ahead of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. These are user settings that can't be overridden by apps. Can you imagine if each app could display alerts any way they wished regardless of the user preference? It would be a mess.

Comment: Well, it would be nice if you could set it on a per-app setting, based on the types of settings allowed by apple (none, banner, alert-view).